# Join + date condition in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have two tables in a database: **Events** and **Dates**, with a one-to-many relationship between them (*1 event can take place along many dates*).

I want to query the database to get the future and past events like this:

- Query to get **future events** should return every event with a date >= CURDATE() **and events with no assigned dates yet**...
- Query to get **past events** should return only events with at least one date assigned which should be, in turn, older than CURDATE()...

I am querying the database using a simple join, getting the appropriate results fot past events (restrictive in not returning events without dates). However, the query for future events is a little bit more tricky, as events without dates have to be also returned. I am open to any suggestion.

My try so far:

**FOR PAST EVENTS (working ok):**

```
SELECT dates.*, events.*,
FROM events
JOIN dates on (events.eventID = dates.eventID AND dates.date < CURDATE())
GROUP BY events.eventID
ORDER BY events.eventID ASC
```

**FOR FUTURE EVENTS:** ???

```
SELECT dates.*, events.*,
FROM events
LEFT JOIN dates on (events.eventID = dates.eventID AND dates.date >= CURDATE())
GROUP BY events.eventID
ORDER BY events.eventID ASC
```

(I am aware my try with **LEFT JOIN** is not valid as it returns also past events, with no date information (every field NULLED)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just need the future events explicitly you may move the `dates.date >= CURDATE()` as having clause

Comment: No, I need the future + non-date events.

Comment: You need the filter to be applied after the join in this case so move the and dates.date>= curdate() to a where clause and add or dates.date is null.  `Where (dates.date>=curdate() OR dates.date is null)`  not often I see this need but nonetheless

Comment: Put your conditions in WHERE clause like xQbert said. Doing like you did, you fetch from dates only those records with dates.date >=CURDATE() excluding those with dates.date = NULL and dates.date < CURDATE()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as you laid them out, your queries don't need a `GROUP BY` clause, as there is no aggregation being done (no `count`, `max`, etc).

You have to separate "join logic" and "condition logic", so I suggest:

Past events:

```
SELECT dates.*, events.*
FROM events
JOIN dates on (events.eventID = dates.eventID)
WHERE dates.date < CURDATE()
ORDER BY events.eventID ASC
```

Future events:

```
SELECT dates.*, events.*
FROM events
LEFT JOIN dates on events.eventID = dates.eventID
WHERE dates.date >= CURDATE()) OR dates.date IS NULL
ORDER BY events.eventID ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If a record in events table will always have a record in the dates table, then you could use

```
SELECT dates.*, events.*,
FROM events
JOIN dates on (events.eventID = dates.eventID AND NVL(dates.date, CURDATE()) >= CURDATE())
GROUP BY events.eventID
ORDER BY events.eventID ASC
```

I guess I don't follow why past events also do not have dates.

Answer (score 0):

i did not even look at the query of "Past Events" because you said its ok.

For the future events one, try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    `events` . *, `dates` . *, MAX(`dates`.`date`) as `maxDate`
FROM
    `events` AS `events`
        LEFT JOIN
    `dates` AS `dates` ON (`events`.`eventID` = `dates`.`eventID`)
GROUP BY `events`.`eventID`
HAVING `maxDate` >= CURDATE()
    OR `dates`.`date` IS NULL
ORDER BY events.eventID ASC;
```